# How can I filter the database that would display into datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have 3 level access, the STUDENT, ADMIN and INSTRUCTOR in a table. so i would like to display only those who are "INSTRUCTOR". thanks im just a newbie in coding.

```
 Me.cboSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 0
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

        Try

            conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sSQL = "SELECT Username, lname + ', ' + fname + ' ' + mname as name, password FROM Instructor"
            If Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "Name" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & " where lname + ', ' + fname + ' ' + mname like '%" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%'"
            Else
                sSQL = sSQL & " where Username =" & Me.txtSearch.Text
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            Me.dtgResult.DataSource = dt
            If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("No record found!")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ErrorToString)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
```

Comment: You mean you have 3 tables, 1 for STUDENT, 1 for ADMIN and the other for INSTRUCTOR?

Comment: only 1 table and I would like to display only those who are Instructor in datagridview since those 3 are in one table.

Comment: Can you provide the table structure plz? I see you querying `FROM Instructor`

Comment: select * from Instructor where level = @user ....

inside "level": Instructor, Admin, Student
and would like to display only those who have "Instructor" in their account.

Comment: Your table name is Instructor? Your @user would contain the word Instructor?

Comment: yes, and @user would contain the word "Instructor, Admin, Student"

Comment: Try the answer below. Hope that's what you meant. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your query part by this;

```
     sSQL = "SELECT Username, lname + ', ' + fname + ' ' + mname as name, password FROM Instructor"
     If Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "Name" Then
        sSQL = sSQL & " where lname + ', ' + fname + ' ' + mname like '%" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%'"
        sSQL = sSQL & " and  level like '%instructor%'"
     Else
        sSQL = sSQL & " where Username =" & Me.txtSearch.Text
        sSQL = sSQL & " and  level like '%instructor%'"
     End If
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Nadeem_MK has the prefered method, let the database do what it is best at, there are times where you want all the data and you need to filter it locally (without another call to the database). One way you could do this is:

```
...Your code
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(dt)
'Filter locally
dim drs as datarow() = dt.select("level = 'Instructor'")
'Use the datarow array as your datasource instead of the data table
Me.dtgResult.DataSource = drs
```

Or, if you are using a "BindingSource", you can filter it too.